# mssql distinct count in subquery

Tags: sql-server

I have sql something like

```
select
name,col2,col3,date
from
table1 join on few tables
```

And result is

```
name col2 col3 date
a    a    a    datetime1
a    a    a    datetime1
b    b    b    datetime2
b    b    b    datetime3
```

and i dont know how to do, but i need to replace date column with column which will
shows count of working days for every name/row

I though about subquery like

```
,(select COUNT(distinct DATENAME(dw, date) NOT IN ('Saturday', 'Sunday')) where name = '...' from ... where ...) as WorkingDays
```

but i need help to get it working, thank you.

Comment: add some sample data and expected resultset please

Comment: provide some fiddle with sample data

Comment: Here is fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1279f

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you want this:

```
SELECT Name, C2,  
       WorkingDays = Sum(CASE WHEN Datename(DW, [date])IN( 'Saturday', 'Sunday' ) 
                         THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) 
                       OVER (PARTITION BY Name) 
FROM dbo.data
```

Here is the sql-fiddle with your sample-data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1279f/14/0

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar: why do you shout? The [`Over` clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) with `Partition By Name` is a window function that groups by name and returns the count per name in every row. That seems to be what OP wants(_"show count of working days for every name/row"_).

Comment: @Muflix: i've added a fiddle with your sample data. Is that the desired result or do you want to group by name instead of listing all rows?

Comment: This is what i needed, i grouped it already, thank you, im adding over function to my sql knowledge :-)

Comment: Then i'm glad that i could help. Remember to accept an answer.

Answer (score 1):

if my understanding is not wrong you just need a groupby of other columns and count of 'date'

```
   select
        name,col2,col3,count(date) as no_of_days
        from
        table1 join on few tables
        where DATENAME(dw, date) NOT IN ('Saturday', 'Sunday')
        group by name,col2,col3
```

Comment: this looks working, i dont realize it could be done that way.. i have to compare result with previous answer with partition function, thank you

Comment: you can try that but i think you will need some alterations like adding columns along with name in partition.@Tim Schmelter

Comment: But have a look at the plan and decide which way is efficient